# Populate a drop down list with post titles across a multisite network

Tags: posts, multisite, plugin-gravity-forms

I have successfully populated a Gravity Forms drop down list with post tiles from  main site in my network. See code below.

What code do I need to add in order to list post titles from sub-sites also?

Any insight is appreciated.

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_20', 'select_questionnaire' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_20', 'select_questionnaire' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_20', 'select_questionnaire' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_20', 'select_questionnaire' );
function select_questionnaire( $form ) {

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if ( $field->type != 'select' || $field->id . '1' === false ) {
            continue;
        }

        $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=questionnaire' );

        $choices = array();
        $choices[] = array("text" => "Select Questionnaire", "value" => "");

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
        }

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be

        $field->choices = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to replace this section:

```
$posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=questionnaire' );

$choices = array();
$choices[] = array("text" => "Select Questionnaire", "value" => "");

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
}

// update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be

$field->choices = $choices;
```

with something like this:

```
$choices = array();
$sites = get_sites();
$choices[] = array("text" => "Select Questionnaire", "value" => "");
foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );
    $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=questionnaire' );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
    }

    // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be

    restore_current_blog();
}
$field->choices = $choices;
```

By default, `get_sites()` returns up to 100 sites. You can filter this with various arguments.

Also, note that if you have a lot of sites in your Multisite network, or a lot of posts in your various sites, you should consider caching your results in a WordPress option or maybe site_option. `switch_to_blog()` can be expensive to run.

### References

- [`get_sites()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/)
- [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/)
- [`restore_current_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/restore_current_blog/)